# 3rd div pushed down inside a div with margin-left/top is applied to the 2nd div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little trouble trying to get the 3rd div to stay inline with the div that it is currently in. You can check it out with  in divboard.css in http://ready4war.net/

Comment: make a minimal working example of your problem and then ask a proper question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your CSS like this it can be ok now it its your job to look if it is ok for you!!

Try to use the inspector to see where a problem commes from

```
.colum2{ 
 display:flex;    
 align-items: flex-end;  /* you can use to flex-start or center*/
 /*height: 100%;*/
 } 

.importantboard {
 /*position: left;*/
 /*float:left;*/
  height: 100%;
}

.battledeck{
/*margin-left: 530px*/
 /*margin-bottom: -24px;*/
 height: 100%;
 }

.twitchboard{
 /*margin-bottom: 24px*/
 /*margin-left: 800px*/
  height: 400px;
  padding-left: 10px;
 }
```